# Net Impulse formula question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, momentum

I am trying to determine the following question -

Imagine a $2kg$ rubberball moving $-10m/s$ impacts a solid wall for $\delta.t$ = $0.02$ seconds
the ball rebounds with +5 m/s gives $J_n$ = $+3~kg.m.s^{-1} $   [$\delta P = P_f~-~P_i$ ]

My question is that if the rubber ball heats during the collision event how would this be expressed in the Impulse formula. Would it be $J_n$ - $K.E.$ lost in the heating event?
Obviously the conservation of energy means some kinetic energy is being lost to the heating event but I'm not sure on how it fits the equation?

many thanks

Comment: You can't subtract Kinetic energy from $J_n$ as both have different units. $J_n$ basically is change in the momentum of ball during the collision. The work-energy equation is $KE_{final}-KE_{initial}=$ heat lost to surroundings during collision.

Comment: Are you saying that Jn is unaffected by any heating of the ball, because KE is directly related to the velocity (1/2 m v sqr)   as it the Impulse F (delta)t.  F=ma. where does the energy to heat the ball come from if not from the velocity component of the ball?

Comment: So a simpler question might be if the ball did not heat during the compression phase, would the ball hit the wall slightly harder?

Comment: See the posted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ball of mass $m$ moving with velocity $u$ in the negative x direction strikes the wall and rebounds with velocity $v$ which is in the positive x direction with $|v|<|u|$. This change in velocity is acquired in very little time, meaning the force applied by wall is very large so the quantity of interest is impulse.
Initial velocity = $-u \hat{i}$ and final velocity = $v \hat i$.
So change in momentum of ball = $F_{avg\;applied\;by\;wall}.\Delta t=m(v+u)\hat i$
By work energy theorem,
$\frac{1}{2}m(v^2-u^2)=$Heat lost to surroundings + Work done on ball
Work f=done on ball by wall is 0 as force is applied by wall on ball when the ball is in contact with the wall, so no displacement.
So, $\frac{1}{2}m(v^2-u^2)=$Heat lost to surroundings    **(1)**

**Case-[1]** From (1), we can see that if $|v|<|u|$, more heat is lost.
And impulse imparted by wall is m(v+u)
Force applied by wall= $\frac{m(v+u)}{\Delta t}$

**Case-[2]** If $|v|=|u|$
Then from (1), $\frac{1}{2}m(v^2-u^2)=0=$Heat lost to surroundings
Meaning no heat is lost (elastic collision).
Impulse imparted by wall is $2mu$
So, force exerted by wall = $\frac{2mu}{\Delta t}$
We can see that force applied by wall is greater in case (2) than in case (1).
And by Newton's Third Law, ball hits the wall harder in case (2) than in case (1).

Comment: There is an incomplete sentence. Second from top.

Comment: I have updated the answer

Comment: Great thanks very much for that detailed explanation.